# cpufreq-set -g performance doesn't work on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, cpu-frequency

`acpi-cpufreq` was already loaded , where the frequency was all 800MHz now , and I can't make it back to full-speed , which is 2500MHz.

I tried `cpufreq-set -g performance` , then I check /proc/cpuinfo , it was still 800MHz

Is there anything wrong ?

**UPDATE**

It's a i5 CPU , part of cpu information provided below:

```
processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4986.76
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: is that an uniprocessor system?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov updated

Comment: `cpufreq-set -g` affects only the first cpu on a multicore system. Try `for i in \`seq 0 3\` ; do cpufreq-set -c $i -g performance; done`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov no lock , still all 800MHz ...

Comment: @DmitriChubarov solved , check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright , this was said to be a bug with Thinkpad ,

When your battery is unplugged , and connected to AC power higher than 65W ,  the freq will stuck at lowest , check the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq/bios_limit` , to see if it's stuck.

Source: `http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_CPU_frequency_scaling`

I got it solved by passing kernel parameter: `processor.ignore_ppc=1`